# Joining two tables with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables like this

```
TABLE A
id | name
1  | a
2  | b
3  | c

TABLE B
id | ida | prp     | prpval
1  |  1  | visible | true
2  |  1  | active  | true
3  |  2  | visible | false
4  |  2  | active  | true
5  |  3  | visible | true
6  |  3  | active  | true
```

Table A and Table B are connected by id-ida. 
I want to display all names(name) from Table A that have property visible(prp) from TABLE B set to 'true' (prpval). Without any duplicates. So in this example i want to display 'a' and 'b'. How to do it?

Comment: How would you come to display `a` and `b` if `b` has `prpval` set to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.name
from a
join b on a.id = b.aid
group by a.name
having sum(case when prp = 'visible' and prpvalue = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't want duplicates, I would approach this using an `exists` clause:

```
select *
from tableA a
where exists (select 1
              from tableB b
              where b.ida = a.id and b.prp = 'visitor' and b.prpval = 'true'
             );
```

For performance, create an index on `tableB(ida, prp, prpval)`.

Comment: What does an exist do compared to an inner join? Will it be faster?

Comment: With an inner join, you might need to do a `distinct` or `group by` to remove duplicates.  That additional processing is unnecessary with `exists`.  I would expect this query to perform well, but as with almost all performance questions, you should try out different versions to see what works on your data on your system.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be:

```
SELECT A.name
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.ida
WHERE B.prp = 'visible'
AND B.prpval = 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
FROM A a join B b on a.id = b.ida
WHERE b.prp = 'visible' and b.prpval = 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name
from A as a
join  B as b on a.id=b.ida 
and b.prpval='True' and b.prp='visible'
```